# Face ID evaluation process not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, touch-id, face-id

I'm trying to get if Face ID or Touch ID succeeded in the function below

```
func authenticate() -> Bool{

    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
        return false
    }
    var returnValue = false
    let reason = "Face ID authentication"
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) 
    {
        isAuthorized, error in
        guard isAuthorized == true else {
            return print(error)
        }
        returnValue = true
        print("success")
    }
    return returnValue        
}
```

but even when it succeeds with this code it skips the `returnValue = true` is passed later which results a false return.
why does this happen? and how can I fix this code to make it work like it is suppose to?

the code above is from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183108/ios-face-id-biometric-integration)
just in case this person was watching, thank you.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, implement error handling when you are ready. For now you have a logical mistake where you are attempting to return when its actually doing an async task. Put a break point with last return statement and the one inside `evaluatePolicy`. You will understand for yourself why returns are failing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try it out and try to understand the code more.

Comment: Here is my updated answer for this, I hope it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73891523/14180967

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Working code of Touch ID & Face ID LocalAuthentication 

#### (swift 4.0 & 5.0+ Code)

> Note : **Privacy - Face ID Usage Description** key add in Info.plist

**Use**

```
self.Authenticate { (success) in
     print(success)
}
```

Local Authentication Function

```
import LocalAuthentication

func Authenticate(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())){
    
    //Create a context
    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error:NSError?
    
    //Check if device have Biometric sensor
    let isValidSensor : Bool = authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)
    
    if isValidSensor {
        //Device have BiometricSensor
        //It Supports TouchID
        
        authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
            .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
            localizedReason: "Touch / Face ID authentication",
            reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in
                
                if(success) {
                    // Touch / Face ID recognized success here
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    //If not recognized then
                    if let error = error {
                        let strMessage = self.errorMessage(errorCode: error._code)
                        if strMessage != ""{
                            self.showAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: strMessage)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(false)
                }
        })
    } else {
        
        let strMessage = self.errorMessage(errorCode: (error?._code)!)
        if strMessage != ""{
            self.showAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: strMessage)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Handle Error Codes with Messages

```
//MARK: TouchID error
func errorMessage(errorCode:Int) -> String{
    
    var strMessage = ""
    
    switch errorCode {
        
    case LAError.Code.authenticationFailed.rawValue:
        strMessage = "Authentication Failed"
        
    case LAError.Code.userCancel.rawValue:
        strMessage = "User Cancel"
        
    case LAError.Code.systemCancel.rawValue:
        strMessage = "System Cancel"
        
    case LAError.Code.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:
        strMessage = "Please goto the Settings & Turn On Passcode"
        
    case LAError.Code.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
        strMessage = "TouchI or FaceID DNot Available"
        
    case LAError.Code.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
        strMessage = "TouchID or FaceID Not Enrolled"
        
    case LAError.Code.biometryLockout.rawValue:
        strMessage = "TouchID or FaceID Lockout Please goto the Settings & Turn On Passcode"
        
    case LAError.Code.appCancel.rawValue:
        strMessage = "App Cancel"
        
    case LAError.Code.invalidContext.rawValue:
        strMessage = "Invalid Context"
        
    default:
        strMessage = ""
        
    }
    return strMessage
}
```

Show alert message

```
//MARK: Show Alert
func showAlertWithTitle( title:String, message:String ) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let actionOk = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(actionOk)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: in your authenticate function, can you show me a way to implement a return bool?

Comment: @Yuto Check my Updated answer for return bool.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> **Note : Privacy - Face ID Usage Description key add in Info.plist**

```
func canAuthenticate() -> Bool {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        return true
    } else {
        // Handle the error, if any
        print("Biometric authentication not available: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        return false
    }
}

func authenticateUser() {
    let context = LAContext()
    
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Authenticate to access the app") { (success, authenticationError) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            if success {
                // Biometric authentication succeeded
                print("Authentication successful")

            } else {
                // Biometric authentication failed or was canceled
                if let error = authenticationError as? LAError {
                    switch error.code {
                    case .userCancel:
                        print("Authentication canceled by the user")
                    case .userFallback:
                        print("User chose to enter password instead")
                        // Handle password entry here if needed
                    default:
                        print("Authentication failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if canAuthenticate() {
        authenticateUser()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a closure to obtain results of evaluation. Note that the return value for `canEvaluatePolicy` is a `Bool` but there is no return value for `evaluatePolicy` as it accepts a closure.

You can modify your method to include a closure instead of return.

```
func authenticate(completion: ((Bool) -> ())) {
    ...
    completion(true) // false if it failed.
    ...
}
```

In other parts of your app, where you earlier used a return value you would now have to use a closure like:

```
class Foo {
   func test() {
       let isEvaluated = self.authenticate() // Old way
       self.authenticate { success in
           // bool will now indicate whether evaluation was done successfully or not.
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: so, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Dont use return. Use a closure like mentioned here.